# User access in IBM Data Cap

Tags: authentication, ldap, dashboard, filenet-p8, ibm-datacap

I have a requirement to show only the jobs started by a specif user in the data cap admin dashboard. The same time I don’t have groups in my LDAP(Active Directory). How this can be achieved within the application. For example if I scan a job then it should be visible to me alone and this applicable to everyone other than the application admin. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to set: store by user on the scan task.
then at the user steps, you would queue by user as well.